How to route from login to specific page in Flutter after notification click?
When the user receives a notification I want to route them to that page. In this case it is a calendar tab that I am routing to.
The problem is if the app is in the background that means the user has lost their current login information.
So when the user clicks on the notification to view their calendar, the app opens up and goes straight to the calendar for 2 seconds then takes them to the login screen.
I want to open the app, check if the user is logged in, send them to the login screen, then forward them to the calendar tab.
Like a Url redirect.
Here is my code where I check for the message and take them to the calendar tab
Future<void> setupInteractedMessage() async {
    // Get any messages which caused the application to open from
    // a terminated state.
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    // If the message also contains a data property with a "type" of "chat",
    // navigate to a chat screen
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      _handleMessage(initialMessage);
    }

    // Also handle any interaction when the app is in the background via a
    // Stream listener
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);
  }

  void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.data['type'] == 'calendar') {
      Provider.of<BN.BottomNavModel>(
              GlobalContextService.navigatorKey.currentContext!,
              listen: false)
          .updateIndex(3);
      Get.offAndToNamed(AppRoutes.main);
    }
  }


I see that you are using GetX for page navigation. While it is simple to use, I feel that it is too limited in functionality. Consider using the go_router package for navigation. It has all the features you are looking for.
